# Flappy search bar : suggestions not updated after Firebase modifications

Tags: firebase, flutter, searchbar

I am quite new to flutter, and I have some issues using this package : https://pub.dev/packages/flappy_search_bar

I am using it with suggestions (made when nothing is written in the search bar), and I have different issues with it, due to the fact that the suggestion list does not update when changes append on Firebase.
Here is my code (in a stateful widget):

```
SearchBarController _searchBarController=SearchBarController();
  List<DocumentSnapshot> documents =[];
  List<LibraryBook> books = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FireHelper().libraryBooksFrom(widget.user.uid).listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        books=getLibraryBooks(documents);
      });
    });

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FireHelper().libraryBooksFrom(widget.user.uid),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData) {
            documents = snapshot.data.docs;
            books=getLibraryBooks(documents);
            return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: white,
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () => setState((){
                  AlertHelper().addBookToLibrary(context);
                }),
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                backgroundColor: pointer,
              ),
              floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
              body: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SafeArea(
                      bottom: false,
                      child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      BackButton(color: Colors.black),
                      MyText(" Ma bibliothèque", color: baseAccent)
                    ],
                  )),
                  Expanded(child: SearchBar(
                      searchBarPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                      onSearch: (inputText) => searchBooks(inputText),
                      suggestions: books,
                      minimumChars: 2,
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      onCancelled: () => searchBooks(null),
                      crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                      onError: (error) => ErrorWidget(error),
                      searchBarController: _searchBarController,
                      hintText: "Chercher un livre...",
                      cancellationWidget: Text("Annuler"),
                      emptyWidget: Text("Aucune correspondance"),
                      onItemFound: (item, int index) {
                        if(item is LibraryBook){
                          return BookLibraryTile(item, null);
                        } else {
                          return Text("Aucune correspondance");
                        }
                      }
                  )
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return LoadingCenter();
          }
        });
  }
```

When I have some changes on Firebase, the list `List<LibraryBook> books` is well updated, but the suggestions of the searchBar does not follow this update...

Any idea ?

[This is what the screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG9W8.png)

EDIT :

[first issue when cancelling a search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbvHz.gif)

[second issue when deleting an item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SmLA.gif)

[third issue when adding a new item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53zJB.gif)
(this one does not append every time... i don't know why)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a state management solution. I suggest checking out the [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package. You need a single model for the books that is shared between widgets.

Also, check out this Flutter [article](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt) on state management if you are not familiar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it did not solve my issues... I edited my question by adding some GIFs to show issues, maybe it is due to something else.. :(

Comment: Ah, thanks gor sharing the GIFs. I now see that you require a more robust solution for your needs. Please check out my updated answer. Good luck.